# MySQL broken after upgrade to 18.04

Tags: 18.04, mysql

MySQL won't start after I upgraded to 18.04 from 16.04 (or maybe 14. I can't quite remember).

I think I know why - `systemctl` does this:

```
Process: 3570 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/mysql start (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
```

which looks successful. However, what actually happened is this, the third line executed in `/etc/init.d/mysql` is this:

```
test -x /usr/bin/mysqld_safe || exit 0
```

which exits because `mysqld_safe` does not exist.

MySQL say this:

> "For some Linux platforms, MySQL installation from RPM or Debian packages includes systemd support for managing MySQL server startup and shutdown. On these platforms, mysqld_safe is not installed because it is unnecessary. "

I think the previous Ubuntu version was 16.04, and the original install was a 12.04.

What should be happening here? Presumably the upgrade left the original `/etc/init.d/mysql` in place?

My initial guess appears to be incorrect. I've done a mysql-server install on a clean live usb and mysqld_safe is there!

dpkg says this on the upgraded system, which can't be good:

rc mysql-server-5.5 5.5.57-0ubuntu0.14.04.1 i386 MySQL database server binaries and system database setup

rc mysql-server-5.7 5.7.24-0ubuntu0.18.04.1 i386 MySQL database server binaries and system database setup

Comment: The above must be included in question with as much as details you can provide. Thanks :-)